# How can I create a dynamic site that is still search-bot friendly?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dynamic

If I want to have a slide effect between pages. You click a link, it is loaded off to the side and then slides in (pushing the old page off the other side). I can imagine using jQuery to do the PHP and the effects... but **how do I do something like this that gracefully degrades for users without Javascript, including bots?**

Possibly more problematic: what if I wanted to have a sort of mural background across the site, perhaps with a parallax scrolling effect, and sliding to other pages reveals more of the, possibly giant image?

Again, I can imagine how to do this with lots of fancy jQuery and PHP but it would heavily rely on those. How can I gracefully degrade in a situation like that?

Any pointers, articles or books would be greatly appreciated. 
I keep trying to search for answers but I just get a lot of "theory"-based, unhelpful blogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your AJAX website be friendly to search bots then you will have to make sure that the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) in the URL changes every time a visitor clicks something to have a content reloaded and, and that identifier starts the exclamation mark to communicate to the bots that your website follows a specific convention. That convention means that the actual content that is displayed by JavaScript using:

```
http://www.example.com/page#!subpage
```

is also served by your server when the bot downloads:

```
http://www.example.com/page?_escaped_fragment_=subpage
```

This is how the [CreateJS](http://www.createjs.com/) website works so when [you google for EaselJS](https://www.google.com/search?q=EaselJS) you get the link to:

```
http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS
```

which is just the same HTML page as for example:

```
http://www.createjs.com/#!/CreateJS
```

but with an information to the client-side JavaScript to dynamically display whatever content is identified with the `#!/EaselJS` fragment identifier.

See [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/) on Google Developers for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Create the basic form of the main page to let the bot get the information it needs and continue with the dynamic contents.

edit: you made a general question which theoretically don't have a specific answer but actually to help you start-up your project i'm doing something like this:

1. client requests a page.
2. server creates dynamically a basic page with the information a bot
   needs and a skeleton with perl, php, xslt or whatever, then posting
   the page
3. client gets the page and loads the **scripts** and begins to
   dynamically creates the contents and moreover doing requests to
   server to get other relevant contents ... like css, other scripts, images ....

edit: to start the dynamic tricks you will use something to make these tricks start-up (probably the first loaded script with the first response from the server), then for users without javascript you have to work more on the basic page and let things work for them (work which has to be done by server side) and if they have javascript your code will start-up and load the tricks.